# Cannot import module 'os' in Electron

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am doing an easy test to try to get my computer's name in an Electron app using Angular and nodejs.

This is my script:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { hostname } from 'os'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(hostname);
  }

}
```

I also installed `npm i @types/node`

I get the following error:

> Error: src/app/components/home/home.component.ts:2:26 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'os' or its corresponding type declarations.
> import { hostname } from 'os'

Any ideas? this should be straightforward and I feel so silly with such a problem...

**Edit:** I added that this is an electron app!!

Comment: os is a module of nodejs, which can't direct use in the angular front end side.

Comment: I am not sure if I want to be greeted with my computer name in the website I am visiting. Webapps can't (and arguably shouldn't) access system level information beyond the browser's sandbox. If this app runs in an isolated environment, then you could expose an API in the backend or the server to return the hostname.

Comment: The fact that this is an Electron app changes... everything. Unfortunately, I don't know Electron.

Answer (score 1):

Before using `import * as os from 'os';`, you have to make sure `"types":["node"]` in the tsconfig.app.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't read his question properly.

the commenter is right you cannot import os to do this on an angular client side application.

instead it should be no imports and you can access via the document, or the window.

**USING DOCUMENT**

```
document.location.hostname
```

or

**USING WINDOW**

```
 window.location.hostname
```

Comment: Module '"os"' has no default export. This does not work! Btw I did not vote down your answer... sadly someone voted me down :S

Comment: I fixed it - sometimes ones own hubris needs a check. in this case it was mine.  sorry again - there are the correct answers document.location.hostname or window.location.hostname you can wildcard them as well document?.location?.hostname and window?.location?.hostname.

Comment: thanks for the answer but this gets the name "localhost". Which I need is my computer's name.

Comment: [`hostname`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/hostname) contains the domain of the URL. Not the host name of the OS.

Comment: im actually looking this up myself.  I see what you want but im not sure if there is a way to look at the local machine name without active x.  you might be able to get it from the machine metadata.  im curious myself now.

Comment: I don't know I was reading this:

require('dns').reverse(req.connection.remoteAddress, function(err, domains) {
    console.log(domains);
});  @Robb

Comment: That is server-side code that will get you a reverse DNS lookup on whatever public IP that I happen to connect through. If I connect from my phone, it will give you the domain of my mobile phone provider.

Comment: this gets pretty complicated he could try and use an http interceptor and get it off the req.headers but im not sure if that would even work properly.  Active X is blocked on like almost all machines now so that probably won't work either.

Im going to look for like 20 more minutes and see if I can't figure this out for them.

Answer (score 0):

this is rather unbelievable but without ActiveX controls it won't work and even then it will work very little because almost all windows based pc's have this disabled by default I believe.

its easy to get the client IP address - but this gets incredibly complex.  You can try http interceptor but that seemed like it was half baked based upon the three hours of my life I dedicated to this.  I'm rather dumb founded to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

The correct code is

```
import * as os from 'os';
```

Usage example :

```
const hostname = os.hostname();
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already tried this. Sadly this doesn't make any difference, I still get the same error.

Comment: it should be import os from 'os' I answered this on a different post.  this is the only correct answer I posed on my own answer the reason why.

Comment: Hello Robby, could you then tell me how to do it properly? Sadly I am no expert on JS frameworks. This is the reason I am asking here.